# How to line up text that is an innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to line break the text for INDIVIDUAL and PHONE. I figured out how to break the text, but I can't get it to line up with the other text.

Current code

```js
document.getElementById("department").innerHTML = department[i]
document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = locationA[i]
document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = peopleCurrentVarStr.replace(/,/g, "<br>")
document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = phoneNumberStr.replace(/,/g, "<br />")
```

```css
span.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>DEPARTMENT: <span class="a" id="department"></span></h1>
<h1>LOCATION: <span class="a" id="location"></span></h1>
<h1>INDIVIDUAL: <span class="a" id="people"></span></h1>
<h1>PHONE: <span class="a" id="phone"></span></h1>
```

[image: My Website]

Comment: The simplest way is to use `<table>` to align columns.

Comment: See the warning here regarding `innerHTML` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: To enhance your question first there is a pending (good) edit. Second you might/should add an example of those values currently undefined: `department,  locationA,  peopleCurrentVarStr, phoneNumberStr`

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I just changed the span to table and it looks good.

Comment: I combined the snippets to allow you to add the values and how you iterate (get the `i`) in play here which likely will result in some good answers since there are several ways to do this (FWIW `<table>` would not be my first choice here since this is about visual and not layout.

Comment: You really have a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl not headings

Answer (score 0):

for your innerHTML you should probably output them into lists `<ul><li></li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should avoid using `innerHTML` when possible due to security and performance implications. And, when the text you are working with doesn't contain any HTML, you definitely shouldn't use `.innerHTML` and instead just use `.textContent`. Then, within your JavaScript strings, you can use the escape code for a new line: `\n`.

Also, your use of `h1` is incorrect. Heading elements (`h1...h6`) should be used to set up document structure, not because of the way they style text. As such, there should rarely be more than one `h1` on a page.

Finally, to your question, if you simply place each piece of data into its own `span` element and, with CSS, set those `span`s to be [`inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), you can then set a width for the two columns of data contained within your elements and you'll be all set:

```js
// Use \n within the string to force a new line
document.getElementById("department").textContent = "TEMP TEXT";
document.getElementById("location").textContent =  "TEMP TEXT";
document.getElementById("people").textContent =  "TEMP TEXT\nMORE TEXT";
document.getElementById("phone").textContent =  "555-666-7777\n888-999-0000";
```

```css
/* Allow the selected SPAN elements to allow for block level formatting
   while still being inline elements. */
span.a, span.category { display:inline-block; }

/* Set widths and styling of specific SPANS */
span.category { width:150px;}
span.a{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- put each piece of data into its own SPAN -->
<div><span class="category">DEPARTMENT: </span><span class="a" id="department"></span></div>
<div><span class="category">LOCATION: </span><span class="a" id="location"></span></div>
<div><span class="category">INDIVIDUAL: </span><span class="a" id="people"></span></div>
<div><span class="category">PHONE: </span><span class="a" id="phone"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the security risk of using `.innerhtml`. I will definitely be  change that. I am new to programming really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is being presented, it looks more like a definition list and a bunch of headlines.

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: visible;
}

dt, dd {
  flex: 50%;
}

dd {
  margin-left: auto;
}

dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>DEPARTMENT:</dt>
  <dd>AA</dd>

  <dt>LOCATION:</dt>
  <dd>BB 1<br/>BB 2<br/>BB 3</dd>

  <dt>INDIVIDUAL:</dt>
  <dd>CC 1<br/>CC 2<br/>CC 3</dd>

  <dt>PHONE:</dt>
  <dd>DD</dd>
</dl>
```